# git format patch --text option and best way to avoid whitespace error

Tags: git

```bash
git format-patch -1 --text --start-number=4 --reroll-count=4 --diff-algorithm=patience
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch

> --text
> Treat all files as text.

I am now only deal with ascii text open source project.
I am not sure  the implication of specifies "--text".
for now with or without text both works.

I want other people apply my patch, no whitespace error, is `--ignore-all-space` is ok?       or what's the best practice?